# How to use Scribe within Codename One?

Tags: java, eclipse, scribe, codenameone

I want to use Scribe within my Codename One project.
Copied the scribe jar file into the library folder. IDE used is eclipse.

When compiling, I get below error :

```
[javac] D:\Vasanth\eclipse_workspace\Testing\src\com\goTime\goTimeVideo\Vimeo.java:19: error: package org.scribe.builder does not exist
[javac] import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
[javac]                          ^
[javac] D:\Vasanth\eclipse_workspace\Testing\src\com\goTime\goTimeVideo\Vimeo.java:20: error: package org.scribe.builder.api does not exist
[javac] import org.scribe.builder.api.VimeoApi;
```

How can I get this issue fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just place JAR into the classpath of Codename One: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/07/jaring-and-libraries.html

You need to use the sources or use native interfaces http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html which support embedding a platform native jar.

Comment: I did include the jar file and I still received the errors I posted previously. So I included the scribe source to my project and managed to include only the files I require and made changes to them. Now I need the HttpURLConnection which cannot be imported from java.net.HttpURLConnection. How can I fix this ?

Comment: You need to adapt the code, that is why the jar won't work. You need to use ConnectionRequest & NetworkManager since java.net.URL etc. aren't implemented for iOS, Windows Phone, RIM etc. 
If you don't change the classpath you will see the error when compiling locally.